# ionic 2 not working with core-js

Tags: angular, ionic2

I found ionic 2 is not working with "@types/core-js": "0.9.34", if I have this, and start ionic serve, I got a lot errors:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts:48:34 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts:48:32 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
```

I have to remove core-js, then ionic serve can start property.

I need core-js as it is required by angular4

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 2 is based on Angular 2, you will have to wait for Ionic 3 to work with Angular 4.

Comment: Today, I start using ionic3, but problem is still there, ASAP I add  "@types/core-js": "0.9.34", and then ionic serve throws a lot errors, same as above. Any idea?